# Trains describing a parabola

Tags: geometry, conic-sections, plane-curves

From the train station – the point S – originante two tracks, i.e. rays, which do not lie on a common straight line.
Along these move two trains, which are line segments.
On the first track a train is moving toward the station S,
while on the other track the second train leaves from the station.
We shall consider the motion of train-segments only for such period of time during which they are leaving the track-rays.

At any fixed time consider a convex quadrilateral whose vertices are the endpoints of the train-segments. In particular, consider the point where its diagonals intersect.

Find out the necessary and sufficient conditions for all these points of intersection to lie on some parabola.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole setup is invariant under affine transformations. Therefore you can (without loss of generality) assume a coordinate system where the incoming train rides on the positive $x$ axis and the outgoing on the positive $y$ axis, and both travel with unit speed. So you'd have the heads of the trains at $(x_1-t,0)$ and $(0,y_1+t)$ and the tails at $(x_2-t,0)$ and $(0,y_2+t)$. Then the point of intersection is

$$
P(t)=
\frac1{(x_2y_1-x_1y_2)-t(x_1-x_2+y_1-y_2)}
\begin{pmatrix}
(t-x_1)(t-x_2)(y_1-y_2) \\
(t+y_1)(t+y_2)(x_2-x_1)
\end{pmatrix}
$$

So this is a rational curve of degree $2$ in $t$. If you compute its implicit form, you will find that it is indeed a conic section. So you want to know when this conic section will be a parabola. For that you care for the limit cases, $\lVert P\rVert\to\infty$. There are two ways how this could happen: either the denominator of the scalar coefficient becomes zero, or you have $t\to\infty$.

\begin{align}
t&\to\frac{x_2y_1-x_1y_2}{x_1-x_2+y_1-y_2} &
t &\to\infty \\
P(t)&\to\lambda\begin{pmatrix}x_1-x_2\\y_2-y_1\end{pmatrix} &
P(t)&\to\mu\begin{pmatrix}y_1-y_2\\x_2-x_1\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

Your curve is a parabola if and only if these two directions agree, i.e. if these two vectors are linearily dependent.

$$
\begin{vmatrix}
x_1-x_2 & y_1-y_2 \\
y_2-y_1 & x_2-x_1
\end{vmatrix} = (y_1-y_2)^2 - (x_1-x_2)^2 = 0
$$

which is simply asking that both trains have the same length – in this coordinate system. Taking our special choice of coordinate system into account, this means that the ratio between length and speed must be the same for both trains:

$$\frac{\ell_1}{v_1} = \frac{\ell_2}{v_2} $$

Comment: MvG,what coordinate system are you using?And can't you write your solutions with more details(sorry, but for me is hard to understand this).

Comment: @Antony: The $x$ axis is chosen in such a way that it points in the direction of one train and its unit length is equal to the distance traveled by that train in one unit of time. The $y$ axis is the same for the other train. Where exactly do you need more detail? Some of the computations I did by CAS (sage in my case), so the details there are hidden in the software. This is particularly true for the formula of $P(t)$ and for the left column of the limit computation.

Comment: MvG,I afrid , that I need all solution .I don't understand how do you get most of formulas .And can't you explain what formulas in brackets mean(I see something like that first time)?

Comment: If you need all the details, you'll have to work them out yourself. Explaining how I did it would make this post too long, since I used projective geometry so I'd have to explain that. But you should be able to compute $P$ from the train endpoints; it's just intersecting two lines. You also should be able to plug the value for $t$ into that formula and cancel common terms. Regarding the notation: I used parentheses to denote [(column) vectors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Column_vector).

Comment: I think I've understand all except   why vectors must be linearily dependent. Can you explain with more details?

Comment: @Antony: Linearily dependent vectors point in the same direction. So if you have two distinct directions for the points at infinity, then you have a hyperbola with two asymptotes. If you only have a single direction, then you have a parabola, and that direction is that of the axis of symmetry.

Answer (score -1):

Some experimentation suggested that the curve (in general a conic) is symmetric about the angular bisector of the two tracks, so that is how I set up my model in Geometry Expressions.
[image: train picture]

One train is located at distance t from the station, the other at u*t+v (so u is the ratio of speeds of the two trains)

The complicated formula is the implicit equation of the curve (most of it is off screen, but here it is in all its glory:

$X^{2}\cdot \left (a^{2}\cdot sin(\theta)^{2}-a\cdot b\cdot sin(\theta)^{2}-a\cdot b\cdot u^{2}\cdot sin(\theta)^{2}+b^{2}\cdot u^{2}\cdot sin(\theta)^{2}\right )+X\cdot \left (2\cdot Y\cdot a\cdot b\cdot sin(\theta)\cdot cos(\theta)-2\cdot Y\cdot a\cdot b\cdot u^{2}\cdot sin(\theta)\cdot cos(\theta)+2\cdot a^{2}\cdot b\cdot sin(\theta)^{2}\cdot cos(\theta)-2\cdot a^{2}\cdot b\cdot u\cdot sin(\theta)^{2}\cdot cos(\theta)-2\cdot a\cdot b^{2}\cdot u\cdot sin(\theta)^{2}\cdot cos(\theta)+2\cdot a\cdot b^{2}\cdot u^{2}\cdot sin(\theta)^{2}\cdot cos(\theta)+4\cdot a\cdot b\cdot v\cdot sin(\theta)^{2}\cdot cos(\theta)-4\cdot a\cdot b\cdot u\cdot v\cdot sin(\theta)^{2}\cdot cos(\theta)\right )-Y^{2}\cdot a^{2}\cdot cos(\theta)^{2}-Y^{2}\cdot a\cdot b\cdot cos(\theta)^{2}-Y^{2}\cdot a\cdot b\cdot u^{2}\cdot cos(\theta)^{2}-Y^{2}\cdot b^{2}\cdot u^{2}\cdot cos(\theta)^{2}-2\cdot Y\cdot a^{2}\cdot b\cdot sin(\theta)\cdot cos(\theta)^{2}-2\cdot Y\cdot a^{2}\cdot b\cdot u\cdot sin(\theta)\cdot cos(\theta)^{2}+2\cdot Y\cdot a\cdot b^{2}\cdot u\cdot sin(\theta)\cdot cos(\theta)^{2}+2\cdot Y\cdot a\cdot b^{2}\cdot u^{2}\cdot sin(\theta)\cdot cos(\theta)^{2}-4\cdot Y\cdot a\cdot b\cdot v\cdot sin(\theta)\cdot cos(\theta)^{2}-4\cdot Y\cdot a\cdot b\cdot u\cdot v\cdot sin(\theta)\cdot cos(\theta)^{2}-4\cdot a^{2}\cdot b\cdot v\cdot sin(\theta)^{2}\cdot cos(\theta)^{2}+4\cdot a\cdot b^{2}\cdot u\cdot v\cdot sin(\theta)^{2}\cdot cos(\theta)^{2}-4\cdot a\cdot b\cdot v^{2}\cdot sin(\theta)^{2}\cdot cos(\theta)^{2}=0$

As there is no term in $X \cdot Y$, we can tell the conic is aligned with the axes.

You can see that this will be a horizontal parabola when the coefficient of $X^{2}$ is 0.

This happens when $\theta=0$ (degenerate situation disallowed by the problem statement) or $a=b$ or $a=b \cdot u^{2}$

Comment: I believe you may have made a mistake assuming a symmetric locus, and consequently the $a=b$ result for $u^2\neq 1$. Take this example: $$B=(6-4t,-3+2t),C=(8-4t,-4+2t),D=(4+2t,2+t),E=(6+2t,3+t)$$ It results in $$F=\left(-10t-42+\frac{288}{6-t},3t-1\right)$$ which describes the hyperbola $$3xy+10y^2-51x-34y+280=0$$ which is not axis-aligned. It is a hyperbola since $$\begin{vmatrix}2\cdot0&3\\3&2\cdot 10\end{vmatrix}=-9<0$$ It is true that the coefficient of $x^2$ is zero, but in this case that only tells us that *one* asymptote of the hyperbola is horizontal.

Comment: The other asymptote in my example above is in direction $(-10, 3)$. That's the one you get for $\lim_{t\to\infty}$. The existence of two distinct asymptotes also implies a hyperbola.